# Active CMS Menu on apphooked object

Tags: django, django-cms

I have an site with Django CMS 3.5.1 and Django 1.11.11 and it has a menu built with CMS. One of its pages is an apphooked list of events. When I click on an event detail, the menu loses its active class.

Here's my menu:

```
{% for child in children %}
    <li class="js-submenuParent {% if child.selected or child.ancestor %}active{% endif %}">
        <a href="{% if child.children %}javascript:void(0);{% else %}{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}" class="{% if child.children %}submenu-btn js-openSubmenu{% endif %}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>

    {% if child.children %}
        <ul class="submenu js-submenu">
            {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I thought `child.ancestor` could solve the problem (or even `child.selected` as it seems I can access the parent's title using `{% page_attribute "page_title" %}`) but it doesn't. Do I have to make a [custom apphook menu](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html#apphook-menus) just to do that or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you attach your application to is the last point the menu system knows about until you integrate a menu for your application.

Adding a menu allows your app URLs to integrate with the menu app via [`NavigationNode(title, url, id)`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html#menus.base.NavigationNode) objects for your URLs.

So if you've got a detail view, you could attach a simple menu;

```
from menus.base import NavigationNode
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from cms.menu_bases import CMSAttachMenu

class EventMenu(CMSAttachMenu):

    name = _("event menu")

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        n = NavigationNode(_('detail page'), "/detail", 1)
        nodes.append(n)
        return nodes

menu_pool.register_menu(EventMenu)
```

The docs on this are here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/menus.html#integration-attach-menus

Based on the above, you could also generate nodes based on lists/querysets etc like you've found with a little investigation;

```
def get_nodes(self, request):
    nodes = []
    for event in Event.objects.published():
        n = NavigationNode(
            event.title,  # title
            event.get_absolute_url(),  # url
            'id_{slug}'.format(slug=event.slug),  # unique ID for node
            visible=False
        )
        nodes.append(n)
    return nodes
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was trying to avoid creating a menu since I have 3 apphooks but I'll try it and let you know if it worked

Comment: It didn't work as well as I expected. It also created a submenu entry for each event I have. Using `{% show_menu 0 1 1 1 %}` and pushing the NavigationNode level to 50 didn't fix it.

Comment: Hold on, I dug deeper into NavigationNode and found the `visible` attribute. Doing `NavigationNode(event.title, event.get_absolute_url(), 1, visible=False)` stopped the events from showing in the menu!

Comment: Can you replace your solution with this slightly modified version so I can accept it? https://pastebin.com/1Dxgrket thanks again!

Comment: @Mærcos I've added to my answer with an example based on your code. I wouldn't be passing 50 as an ID for all your nodes though because that's a unique value so you'll need to come up with something that's unique

Answer (score 1):

This was a regression introduced in the 3.5.x and 3.4.x menu enhancements.

It has been fixed and will be released on 3.5.3 and 3.4.7

Related ticket: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6336

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it